# how to configure cxf bus to specify servlet context (the /cxf part)?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, bus, blueprint-osgi

Up until now I have been using apache cxf to host some web services, and my bus is configured in `blueprint.xml` like so:

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

The web application is available on `http://localhost:8182/cxf/myservice`.

Basically, I would like to be able to specify the `/cxf/` part - how can I do this?

For example:

The web application is available on `http://localhost:8182/foo/myservice`.

(Note that in my case, I actually want to configure 2 cxf buses... one at `/cxf` and one at `/foo`...)

Edit: I want to clarify, since I need to configure 2 different buses, that a "global" setting for property `org.apache.cxf.servlet.context=/xyz` does not solve my problem.

I need something like this:

```
<!-- first bus -->
<cxf:bus id="cxf">
    <!-- configure context to /cxf somehow... -->
    <cxf:features>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>

<!-- second bus -->
<cxf:bus id="foo">
    <!-- configure context to /foo somehow... -->
    <cxf:features>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

Comment: http://ulhasbhole.blogspot.ru/2012/04/quick-note-on-how-to-removechange-cxf.html

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve my problem, please see my edit.